# Create Multiple Custom Modules - Not Working

Tags: database

I have written this schema for creating 2 tables in my custom module.install

```
    <?php
function my_registration_form_schema() {
    $schema = array();

 $schema['myuser'] = array
(
      'description' => t('The table containing users who have signed up for the chance to register.'),
      'fields' => array
        (
        'id' => array
        (
        'description' => t('Primary Key ID'),
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
      'first_name' => array
        (
        'description' => t('User\'s First Name'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
      'last_name' => array
        (
        'description' => t('User\'s Last Name'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        ),    
        'email_address' => array
        (
        'description' => t('User\'s Email Address'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'user_country' => array
        (
        'description' => t('Country name of user'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 50,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'user_city' => array
        (
        'description' => t('City name of user'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 50,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
      'address' => array
      (
        'description' => t('User address'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length'=>600,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'gender' => array
      (
        'description' => t('User gender'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length'=>10,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array( 'id' ),
);



    $schema['userdata'] = array
    (
      'description' => t('The table containing additional data about user.'),
      'fields' => array
      (
        'id' => array
        (
        'description' => t('Primary Key ID'),
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
      'subscribe' => array
      (
        'description' => t('User Subscription'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'dob' => array
      (
        'description' => t('User date of birth'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length'=>15,
        'not null'=>TRUE,
      ),
      ),
        'primary key' => array( 'id' ),

    );

  // Return the Table Schema
  return $schema;
}
```

When I had only one table, myuser, it was working good.
Now Its not.. What is wrong with code.
Please Help

Comment: try without `$schema = array();` in your line 3, to see what will happen...

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? How it supposed to work?

Comment: @mixerowsky - Tried removing that.. but did not work

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda - Actually when i install this module, only first table is getting created in my db. Second one not created

Comment: Try uninstalling the module (not just disabling)  and installing it again?

Comment: I believe you need to set your userdata->id to be serial rather than int, so that your primary key auto-increments? See [schema API] (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21schema.inc/group/schemaapi) manual 'fields' -> type

Comment: @longboardnode in that case it should left logs in `syslog` ?

Comment: Regardless, I believe you still need one field to be serial and auto-increment... see the example in the page in my previous comment.